# Why does my angular2 app initialize twice?

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-routing

Please tell me where my mistake is, my app is running the AppComponent code twice.
I have 5 files:

**main.ts:**

```
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent, environment } from './app/';
import { APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from './app/routes';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http';
import {ServiceProvider} from "./app/providers/app.service.provider"

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ServiceProvider, APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS, HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
```

**routes.ts**:

```
import {provideRouter, RouterConfig} from '@angular/router';
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";
import {ReportDetailComponent} from "./component/AppReportDetailComponent";
import {ReportsListComponent} from "./component/AppReportListComponent";
import {ReportCreateComponent} from "./component/AppReportCreateComponent";


export const routes:RouterConfig = [
    {
      path: 'reports',
      children: [
        {path: ':id', component: ReportDetailComponent},
        {path:'', component: AppComponent },
        {path: 'create', component: ReportCreateComponent},
        {path: 'list', component: ReportsListComponent},
      ]
    }
  ];
export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [provideRouter(routes)];
```

**app.component:**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ReportNavComponent} from "./component/AppReportNavComponent";
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'tpl/app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css'],
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ReportNavComponent]

})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<report-nav></report-nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

and last **AppReportNavComponent.ts:**

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: "report-nav",
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  template: `<nav>
  <a [routerLink]="['/list']">List</a>
  <a [routerLink]="['/create']">Create new</a>
</nav>`
})

export class ReportNavComponent {
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

if I go to /reports I should  see two links "List" and "Create"
but inside app-root tag  I see the secondary app-root tag (on the picture)
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5TA0.png)
And my question is: why?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because your default route points to `AppComponent`, so your route is rendering the `AppComponent` inside the `AppComponent`:

```
{path:'', component: AppComponent },
```

You probably should put there a `DashboardComponent` or `HomeComponent`.

Comment: So, I should use router outlet in dashboardcomponent and dashboardcomponent call into app.component?

Comment: No, the other way round. The `AppComponent` is the entry point to your app. And that dashboard needs to be set in the route config: `{path:'', component: DashboardComponent },`

Comment: Also the route should have `pathMatch: 'full'` if it has an empty path and no child routes