# Angular2 component reloads twice for no reason

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular2-template

Im working on an angular2 RC4 app and I started to notice something weird.
I have a bunch components I can route to:

```
Parent(A) - ManyChildren(B,C,D,E)
```

My component A gets the ID, talks to a service to get an item and updates the state. Other components listen to state "selectedItem" with BehaviorSubjects.

```
 path: ':id/steps',
```

Everything works, except for some unpredictable behavior when I try to navigate by URL as a completely new reload(new window).

When I try to reload my page completely (assuming the user wants to bookmark a page), I get routed to the correct page and all the values are set properly.
HOWEVER, as I try to navigate into the same tree, component A reloads AGAIN.

I would go to

```
localhost/items/1/steps/step1
```

Parent A constructor runs. As I go to

```
localhost/items/1/steps/step2
```

Parent A constructor runs again. This is really unacceptable to me as I expect my component to be loaded once and exactly once.Am I missing something?(RC4)

Comment: Please add your routes and said components codes.

Comment: Are you using angular2 release or an alpha/rc? Because router changed a lot and previous versions (the current one is known as the v3) were buggy.

Comment: How do you know that Parent A constructor is running again?

Comment: I can put console log in there and see that it's being logged twice

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason of this behaviour. It's strange.
But as the documentation says in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html you should keep your service logic into ngOnInit() instead of constructor:

> Don't fetch data in a component constructor. You shouldn't worry that a new component will try to contact a remote server when created under test or before you decide to display it. Constructors should do no more than set the initial local variables to simple values.

I don't know if it'll fix your problem. Try it and let us know.

Comment: I moved code in all underlying components to ngOnInit(), and it's the same exact behavior - ngOnInit() ran twice for component that was getting ID from route

Answer (score 0):

Here [Why does my angular2 app initialize twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38378022/why-my-angular2-app-inicialize-twice) another user have the same behaviour because he configured the AppComponent as default route. Maybe your problem is similar to this? We have really few information to understand and solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

After some time I found the error. Since we are still at RC4, and at the time we were setting up our build system - we have set up some lazy loading with WebPack.
For whatever reason, it is what was causing the reload.

```
        path: 'clients',
        component: 'ClientsComponent',
        //canActivate: [WebpackAsyncRoute], << THIS LINE // Async components with children routes must use WebpackAsyncRoute
        children: [
```